# Xcode storyboard resizing controller scene after adding segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

In one particular situation in storyboard I'm getting annoying issue.
I have one controller with 2 segue to it.

***First Segue:*** from **UIController(1 from pic)** to **UIController(3 from pic)** all looks fine

***Second Segue:*** from **ContainerView(2 from pic)** to **UIController(3 from pic)** makes target **UIController(3, 4 from pic)** scene shrink to the same height like **ContainerView(2 from pic)**. How to avoid it? Items 2 and 3 should have same height like item 1.

[image]

How to fix it in storyboard?

P.S. When I'm running app all looks fine

Comment: Add new UINavigationController in front of VC 3. Or make VC 3 appears full screen via code

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, simply set **Page Sheet** in simulation metrics

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by setting the storyboard segue to custom.

[image]

However, IMHO a custom segue should only be used if the default segues of the iOS SDK are not sufficient. Creating a custom segue requires you to subclass the UIStoryboardSegue class and override the method, named **perform**. This method will contain the custom animation logic to be implemented.